Указать кодировку html страниц через системный файл
В html документе, прописываю
<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>

Прочитал, что тоже самое делается через htaccess
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Удалил тег и выставил
AddDefaultCharset windows-1252


Или пишут неверно, что это одно и тоже. Или не на той строчке прописал...
Не меняется заголовок

Server: nginx — ну если файл отдаётся не апачем, то вполне логично, что настройки апача на это влиять никак не могут

Конфиге прописано charset off;

Через php удается изменить, через  htaccess увы. В конфиге php выставлена, получается ни в html ни в htaccess нет необходимости выставлять кодировку...

Если все html-файлы зачем-то проходят через php и он сам выставляет кодировку, то тогда каких-либо действий со стороны апача наверное тоже логично не ожидать
